# Why should I overload a C++ operator as a global function (STL does) and what are the caveats?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, global

Why would I want to overload a C++ operator() as global and not member function. For example, the `==` operator.

Why is this done? for example in STL libraries.

Comment: I generally let questions percolate a few hours at least before choosing an answer. You never know who's going to come along with an answer that blows all the previous answers out of the water.

Comment: That might very well be. But the answer you accepted doesn't really answer the question and goes on about somewhat irrelevant things. In my opinion, the best answer here is James Kranze's, which illustrates my point about waiting to accept very nicely.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The usual rule is for operators which modify the left hand object to be
members, and binary operators which return a new object to be free
functions; the main motivation for the latter is because the compiler
will not convert the left hand side to match a member; if your class
supports **any** implicit conversions, then all of the usual binary
operators should be free functions, so that the same rules of conversion apply
for the left hand side and the right hand side, e.g.:

```
class Complex
{
public:
    Complex(double r, double i = 0.0);
    bool operator==( Complex const& other ) const;
};

Complex a;
//  ...
if ( a == 1.0 ) // OK
//  ...
if ( 1.0 == a ) // error.
```

but:

```
class Complex
{
public:
    Complex(double r, double i = 0.0);
    friend bool operator==( Complex const& lhs, Complex const& rhs ) const;
};

Complex a;
//  ...
if ( a == 1.0 ) // OK
//  ...
if ( 1.0 == a ) // OK
```

One elegant way of achieving this is to define the basic operations in
terms of member functions—for things like `+` or `-`, these would
be `operator+=` and `operator-=`; for comparison, you'd need to define
an arbitrary conventions, a member `isEqual`, or `compare` (which would
return `<`, `==` or `>` zero according to the results, then inherit from
a template along the lines of:

```
template <typename T>
class ArithmeticOperators
{
    friend T operator+( T const& lhs, T const& rhs )
    {
        T result( lhs );
        result += rhs;
        return result;
    }
    //  And so on, for all of the binary operators.
};

class Complex : public ArithmeticOperators<Complex>
{
public:
    //  ...
    Complex& operator+=( Complex const& other );
    //  etc.
};
```

Note that there is some argument for making the `operator <op>=`
functions free functions as well: the fact that the free function will
take a non-const reference as its first argument, and thus requires an
lvalue (like the built-in `operator <op>=`).  This doesn't seem to
be the usual practice, however, probably because `operator=` must be a
member, and it seems more natural to treat the `operator <op>=` in
the same mannter.

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly,  `operator =` must be a member function. Regarding `operator ==`, I figure you don't actually mean global but free function instead (STL does not define operators globally). There are a couple of things to consider, one is decoupling from the class itself: If your operator can be defined in terms of the public interface of your class, then you are better off implementing it that way to keep the access to the implementation internals to the bare minimum. The other fundamental advantage is the possibility to implemement an operator where your type comes as the second operand, consider equality between types T and U:

```
bool operator ==( T const& t, U const& u ){ ... }
bool operator ==( U const& t, T const& u ){ ... }
```

If objects of type T and U can be equally compared, then it makes sense that both `t == u` and `u == t` are valid and both yield the same result. If you were defining this operator as a member function, then one would be within the implementation of T and the other within the implementation of U. Now consider U is a 3rd party type outside your control, or even better is a fundamental type such as `int`, now there is no other way for you to provide such operator but to provide the free function version of it.

Comment: @unixman83: This is valid for any types T and U, be it `int`, `my_class`, `std::string` or whatever you can think of.

Answer (score 0):

The rules for matching a member function against an argument are different from the rules for matching the first argument of a free function. I'm not certain exactly how they are different, but since they are different it's actually preferable to implement most binary operators as free functions instead of member functions in order that argument matching operates symmetrically for both arguments.

There is an except for postfix `++`, but that's because it isn't really a binary operator, and only plays one when you overload it in order to have a way of distinguishing between it and prefix `++`.

Comment: by *symmetrically* he means that they will both call into the same code (usually the same function) instead of calling into whichever class is on the left-side of the `=operator`.

Comment: The main difference is that in the case of a member function, the compiler is not allowed to apply implicit conversions on the left-hand-side of the operator: `5+x` where `x` is of a type `T` implicitly convertible from `int` will never call `T::operator+(T const &)`, but it can call `operator+(T,T const&)` breaking symmetry between the expressions `5+x` and `x+5`. Additionally, pass-by-value optimization in the free signature cannot be applied in the case of a member function, that will require an extra copy. ([more](http://definedbehavior.blogspot.com/2011/07/operator-overloading.html))