# Bignum Arithmetic. C++ class

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, biginteger, bigint

I recently started to study classes and operator overloading in C++, and wrote following Bignum class in order to pratice. Link: http://pastebin.com/cQNwRChx. It's not a final version, for example there is no exception handling and maybe it's not so effective, so I want to clarify some questions:

1. This code is successfully compiled in MSVS 2010, but GNU C++ 4.4.1 says, that *'fft' was not declared in this scope* in line 465.
2. I use Fast Fourier transform to multiply numbers when the result is huge. Because of very slow standard complex numbers, I wrote my own implementation. In my opinion, these complex numbers should be hidden, because it's like a part of Lint implementation. So I declare it as a private nested class of Lint, and declare fft as a friend of Lint. Why it doesn't work in GNU?
3. The debugger of MSVS shows, that constant ONE isn't a static constant. It's defined below, after Lint's definition.
4. I would like to use class with int, unsigned int and etc. in expressions, and current version works fine, but also I want to have an opportunity to write something like this: `if (a) ...`, where a is Lint. But if I define implicit conversion to bool and write `a+b`, where a is int and b is Lint, there is an ambiguity. How can I solve this problem?

UPD. There is a simple pseudo-code without excess functions and definitions: http://pastebin.com/rauKQjtH.

Comment: This is an interesting code but it’s completely out of scope for feedback here. Please create a **minimal, complete version** of the code that still exhibits the problem and remove any irrelevant code – people will be much more likely to look at it.

Comment: it compiles on g++ 4.6.3 without warnings...

Comment: this code compiles ok on gcc 4.7.1, also please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578682/why-should-i-overload-a-c-operator-as-a-global-function-stl-does-and-what-ar

Comment: For question 4, use `explicit operator bool() const` if C++11 is allowed, otherwise google "Safe-Bool-Idiom". Also, you might find my [df.operators](https://github.com/d-frey/operators/) library useful (again if C++11 is an option, otherwise check out [Boost.Operators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/utility/operators.htm))