# Overload operator in struct

Tags: c++, struct, overloading, operator-keyword

My struct is as follows:

```
struct pixel{

int val;
int x;
int y;

pixel(int v = 0, float l = 0, float h = 0)
{
    val = v;
    x = l;
    y = h;
}


 bool operator == (const pixel &p1, const pixel &p2)  //ERROR
{

     if(p1.val() == p2.val()) return true;
     else return false;

}


};
```

I have 2 pixels (12 ,0,1) and (66, 2 , 2)
I want to compare if they have the same value which is 12 not equal 66

my main would be:

```
int main()
{
pixel b;
  b.val=12;
b.x=0;
b.y=1;

pixel c;
c.val=66;
  c.x=2;
 c.y=2;

 if(b==c) //ERROR
  { ///do sth
  }
return 0;
    }
```

error is in operator overloadin: too many parameters, it should take 1 pixel as parameter but how is it going to compare???

Comment: Your operator is defined as a member function. Either move it outside of the struct or remove the second argument.

Comment: operator== takes one arg.  The other one is `this`

Comment: @stark can you provide an answer??

Comment: @KurtStutsman if it is inside the struct.. how will I compare?

Comment: Some background reading on choosing an operator as a member vs. "free function": [post one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622330/), [post two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578682/), [post three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145022/)

Comment: `bool operator== (const pixel& p2) const { return this.val == p2.val; }`

Comment: @stark error this must have a class type