# Overloading gives me error: no match for ‘operator<’

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, casting, operator-overloading

In code I have queue of `Events` sorted by `waitTime`. I want to find which `Events` should be executed for the current moment, so I do this:

```
std::vector<Event>::iterator up = std::upper_bound(queue.begin(), queue.end(), currentTime);
```

The `std::upper_bound` will work if I overload `<` operator:

```
bool Event::operator<(const double& currentTime) const
{
    return waitTime < currentTime;
}
```

But I have an error:

```
   error: no match for ‘operator<’ (operand types are ‘const double’ and ‘Event’)
```

How should I correctly overload  ‘operator<’ ?

P.S

```
class Event{
public:
    double startTime;
    double waitTime;
    double size;

    Event(double start, double wait, double size);
    bool operator<(const Event& otherEvent) const;
    bool operator<(const double& currentTime) const;
    bool operator() (const Event & event, const double & right);
};
```

Comment: What is endTime?

Comment: And `Event` are defined as ... ?

Comment: Please post a [mcve], not disjointed code fragments.

Comment: btw looks extremely fishy that you use `<=` to implement `<`, in general those two impose quite different orderings

Comment: Note that once you get this to compile, there's still a serious problem: `waitTime <= currentTime` is not a strict weak ordering, so the behavior of the code is undefined. The problem is that when `waitTime` is equal to `currentTime`, that `operator<` reports **both** that `waitTime` comes before `currentTime` **and** that `currentTime` comes before `waitTime`.

Comment: I've changes to the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking into account this error message

> error: no match for ‘operator<’ (operand types are ‘const double’ and
>   ‘Event’)

you need to declare the operator

```
bool operator<(const double &, const Event &);
```

It seems that within the algorithm there is used the condition

```
currentTime < *it
```

Another approach is to call the algorithm like

```
std::vector<Event>::iterator up = std::upper_bound(queue.begin(), 
                                                   queue.end(), 
                                                   Event { 0.0, currentTime, 0.0 });
```

that is by using casting of `currentTime` to an object of the type `Event` because there is already overloaded operator < for objects of the type `Event`..

```
bool operator<(const Event& otherEvent) const;
```

Answer (score 2):

This might be really useful.
The following link deals with **global operator overrides**, and the limitations thereof, as well as the use of the *friend* keyword in C++ 11.

[link] [Why should I overload a C++ operator as a global function (STL does) and what are the caveats?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578682/why-should-i-overload-a-c-operator-as-a-global-function-stl-does-and-what-ar)

Answer (score 2):

```
bool Event::operator<(const double& currentTime) const
```

Defines the less-than operator for *only* the following situation:

```
Event e;
//...
double d = /*...*/;
bool result = e < d;
```

**NOT** the following situation

```
bool result = d < e;
```

When defining these operators, you MUST define them both ways! Ideally define them both as **non-member** functions

```
bool operator<(const Event& e, const double& currentTime);
bool operator<(const double& currentTime, const Event& e);
```

(Why nonmember functions? To [improve encapsulation](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197))

John Lakos has a [has a wonderful CPPcon talk](https://youtu.be/W3xI1HJUy7Q?t=2507)  where he says exactly this.